# How to map/bind mouse button as keyboard button in Windows 7?

Tags: windows, keyboard, mouse

I'm trying to map/bind my mouse `button 4` and `button 5` to behave as kayboard `num pad 1` and `2`, does exist some way to do that? Maybe with some specific software?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try [**X-Mouse Button Control**](http://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/XMouseButtonControl.htm):

> X-Mouse Button Control is a Windows application to remap your mouse buttons and expand the capabilities of your mouse!
>
> The extensive list of functions available to map to your mouse buttons includes options such as:
>
> - Send any keys using the simulated keystroke editor
> - Launch any windows application
> - Copy/Cut/Paste
> - Media control (play/pause/stop/volume/mute etc.)
> - Capture screen (or active window) image to clipboard
> - Click-Drag [Sticky buttons/keys]
> - Vista (and Windows 7) support with some Vista/7 only features such as 'Flip 3D'
> - And much more!

[image: 1]

Comment: Once you've installed X-Mouse Button Control, to set up a key mapping, right click on the mouse icon in the notification area ('system tray'), and choose Setup. Then, from the drop down list for the mouse button you want to map, pick the "Simulated Keys" option; that will open the dialog shown above, and you can enter a code for the keys you want pressed as explained there.

Comment: Unfortunately, it cannot be used in a remote desktop session.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly I would recommend looking into a program called AutoHotKeys. It will allow you to creat scripts that enable customization over what happens when certain keys are pressed together, how many times they should be pressed, if the mouse should be clicked(left or right), where the mouse should move, and so on...