# Map single key press to a double tap (Windows)

Tags: keyboard

Is there any way to map the single press of a key to a double press of a different one? E.g. I press the Q button (tap it, rather than hold it down), and it maps to pressing the 1 key twice in quick succession? I'm using 64-bit Windows 7.

(Background: I am playing a new game, Batman Arkham Origins, that has very poor keyboard and mouse support compared to previous games in the series. I think I'll be able to get around its lack of support for extra mouse buttons and inability to use shift as a modifier key using [this past superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/562972/how-to-map-bind-mouse-button-as-keyboard-button-in-windows-7). But that still leaves the problem that actions that were previously two different keyboard mappings (using a gadget normally and "quickfire") are now mapped to the same key that you press either once or twice.)

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I promise I searched before posting! But it looks like [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) will do the trick here, assuming that it works with the game. Sorry about the noise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the record, to do this in AutoHotkey you need a mapping like this in your script:

`q::Send 11`

This will simulate two presses of the 1 key in immediate succession. It will only work if the Q key is pressed with no modifiers, like shift or control. If you want it to work with modifiers held down, put an asterisk at the front like this:

`*q::Send 11`

Anyone interested in the same specific problem as me, namely making the controls to Arkham Origins bearable, can find the full script I made in this [forum post](http://steamcommunity.com/app/209000/discussions/0/792924952690848586/).

Answer (score 0):

Download [Macro Recorder](http://www.jitbit.com/macro-recorder/). With it, record a double click macro (make sure delay is set to either zero or a minuscule time), and assign it to the letter Q.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But as I said in the comment on my original post, I already realised that AutoHotkey could do this. The program you've posted looks interesting, but not as good as AutoHotkey and also not free. I've posted an answer now to help others with this.